# REST Framework for .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, rest, basic-authentication

I am looking for a simple .NET REST Framework to write a simple web service with.  The web service will be consumed by a Blackberry application, so my requirements aren't too strict hopefully:

- Supports custom Basic Authentication (against a database of users)
- Supports GET and POST.
- Supports both JSON and XML.  (XML is something I am not fussed about, so it's not mandatory)
- Supports custom serialization of objects (I have some currently existing POCOs, which are decorated with DataMember attributes, so it would be good to keep using those classes)
- Must be simple!
- Preferably supports .NET 4.0. (I am not sure if it is possible to run class libraries compiled against .NET 3.5 on 4.0, but if it is, 3.5 would certainly do)
- Runs on IIS6.

Of those, the basic authentication one is the major requirement.

I prototyped up a web service using the WCF REST Starter Kit, and it was pretty simple to get up and running, but it's all gone a bit oddly pear-shaped to be honest. Plus, it was only a prototype, and with the starter kit not being developed any more, it would probably be a good idea to re-implement it.

Would something like OpenRasta do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely give WCF HTTP a shot (it's the latest bits from the WCF team and replaces the old hack-y REST Starter Kit). You can download it from Codeplex at:

[WCF Community Site - WCF HTTP](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP)

If that doesn't work for you, you could always fall back to ASP.NET MVC and simply return JSON objects from your Action Methods.

Comment: Would love to use the new bits of WCF HTTP, but I haven't been able to find a really good article on custom basic authentication. It's a difficult thing to search for, as a lot of the articles out there deal with older versions of WCF.

Comment: @ScottD - Looking in to it now (seeing if I can get a response from the WCF team that worked on the HTTP bits).

Comment: @ScottID @Justin  Maybe you should wait until tomorrow... :-)

Comment: @ScottD - Just heard back from the WCF Team...basic auth support in WCF HTTP is supported the same way as it was in regular WCF.